# Spring Batch : parallel steps execution in java configuration file

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to make a sample application on parallel step execution in java configuration file but get perplexed that how many files(job repository,job launcher and execution etc.) are being configured and initialized and if configured then how? 
Simply I need a sample application to clarify the basics of parallel execution of steps in a job.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example of using splits via java config.  In this example, flows 1 and 2 will be executed in parallel:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Tasklet tasklet() {
        return new CountingTasklet();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flow flow1() {
        return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow1")
                .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                        .tasklet(tasklet()).build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flow flow2() {
        return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow2")
                .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                        .tasklet(tasklet()).build())
                .next(stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
                        .tasklet(tasklet()).build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(flow1())
                .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).add(flow2())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    public static class CountingTasklet implements Tasklet {

        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s has been executed on thread %s", chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepName(), Thread.currentThread().getName()));
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Because I only want to know that how can multiple steps run in parallel. So It gives me an idea.

Comment: @MichaelMinella I am having a scenario where the number of flows depends on number of rows in a table. So each flow should be running taking each row as input. Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: This is the answer ! Also you do not need to set tasklet if you want. It will work without tasklet in each step also

Comment: @NitishKumar Is your comment response to mine?

Comment: @Ganapathi004 No

Comment: Could you provide example how execute step1 and after its termination start step2 and step3 in parallel ?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you have steps, A,B1,B2,B3,C. You want to run B1,B2 & B3 in parallel. You first need to create sub-flows for them and then add to one flow with SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor():

```
@Bean
public Job job()
{
    final Flow flowB1 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("subflowb1").from(stepb1()).end();
    final Flow flowB2 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("subflowb2").from(stepb2()).end();
    final Flow flowB3 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("subflowb3").from(stepb3()).end();

    final Flow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("splitFlow")
        .start(flowB1)
        .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
        .add(flowB2, flowB3).build();

    return jobBuilderFactory
       .flow(stepA())
       .next(splitFlow)
       .next(stepC())
       .end()
       .build();
}
```

Comment: the syntax is a bit confusing: does invoking flowB1 in start, then calling split and then add ensure all 3 run in parallel or just B2 and B3?

Answer (score 0):

here is the basic parallel step execution on different data set, basically you have to provide a Partitioner which will create seprate context for each step and based on context you can work on its data set.

```
<batch:job id="myJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
                <batch:step id="master">
                    <batch:partition step="step1" partitioner="stepPartitioner ">
                        <batch:handler grid-size="4" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
                    </batch:partition>
                </batch:step>

            </batch:job>

        <batch:step id="step1">
                <batch:tasklet>
                    <batch:chunk reader="myReader" processor="myProcessor" writer="myWriter"
                                 commit-interval="10"/>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>


    public class stepPartitioner implements Partitioner {

        @Autowired
        DaoInterface daoInterface;

        @Override
        public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int i) {
            Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();

            List<String> keys= daoInterface.getUniqueKeyForStep();
            for(String key: keys){


                    ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
                    executionContext.putString("key", key);

                    result.put(key,executionContext);


            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: that is not a javaconfig example

Comment: yeah @sandeep thats not javaconfig example.. I need all in javaconfig.